# Don't have enough memory to build phantom.js - what to do?

Tags: linux, gcc, build, phantomjs

I am trying to compile phantom.js on VPS server (1Gb RAM). Build process generates an error (persistently):

```
obj/svg/SVGAllInOne.o svg/SVGAllInOne.cpp
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:168320: Warning: end of file not at end of a line;         
newline inserted
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing              
.cfi_endproc directive
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

I found problem with the same file here http://forum.qt.io/topic/22672/g-crash-when-compiling-qt5. People say there: not enough memory.

What can I do in this situation? Information on Phantom.js site says that it should be build from source.

Addition: it's definitely out of memory situation cause I just got message from provider saying that server run out of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add swap partition for your VPS or you can just add swap file to extend your virtual memory: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/.

Also you can try to build phantom.js on the other system which have more memory and then copy it to the target VPS. But you need to be sure that both systems have the same architecture and the same environment (versions of compiler, libraries etc).

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading about cross-compiling now and I think it's the case. I'll try to make sure that versions of libraries and compiler are the same. The first isn't choice for me cause permissions to manage swap are not granted by hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I rerun build.sh passing `--jobs 1` and it worked.